# Slow Boot in Ubuntu 22.04 - Geoclue issue?

Tags: boot, 22.04

I run ubuntu 22.04 and today my computer started being very slow to reboot (I was having trouble with nordvpn and was trying multiple things to fix it following their support team advice. When I restarted my system following their instructions I got the slow boo issue). It gets to the login screen at the usual speed, but after I put my password it goes to a black screen and  takes a few minutes to load the desktop. I looked at my log with `journalctl --since today` and there was a 1 minute and a half gap apparently due to geoclue (see output below showing the jump in time around the time I have the issue with geoclue). What should I do?

I tried just removing geoclue with `sudo apt-get remove geoclue-2.0`. However, it also wants to remove the following packages: `gdm3 geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gnome-calendar gnome-control-center  gnome-initial-setup gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock libgeoclue-2-0 ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session`. What should I do in this case to solve my issue?

I am not a super experienced user, so let me know if I am wrong. Thanks for your help!

LOG OUTPUT:

```
nov 23 13:38:10 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2619]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
nov 23 13:38:10 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2627]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
nov 23 13:38:10 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2629]: /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent: linha 9: has_option: comando não encontrado
nov 23 13:38:12 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
nov 23 13:38:12 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
nov 23 13:38:13 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
nov 23 13:38:15 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
nov 23 13:38:42 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 geoclue[1615]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
nov 23 13:38:42 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/roberto
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=roberto
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID=2021
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=2
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/roberto
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=roberto
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=roberto
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/home/roberto/.local/share/flatpak>
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/roberto/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin>
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=ubuntu
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
nov 23 13:40:19 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2645]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
nov 23 13:40:20 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 dbus-daemon[2045]: [session uid=1000 pid=2045] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.23' (uid=1000 >
nov 23 13:40:20 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 systemd[2021]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
nov 23 13:40:20 roberto-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15IMH05 dbus-daemon[2045]: [session uid=1000 pid=2045] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
```

Comment: The package should be `geoclue-2.0`.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Are you using redshift by chance?  `geoclue-2.0` is default installed into GNOME (Ubuntu) Desktop.

Comment: How can I check if I am using redshift? I am not sure

Comment: Actually, check your location services in settings and make sure that they are enabled.  There is possibly a chance that geoclue is hanging up on trying to locate and it doesn't have permission.

Comment: One other thing possibly to try, and I just had to do this because geoclue for me would hang up on finding my location with or without location services turned on, but I did the git install of it https://github.com/freedesktop/geoclue and then had to restart my system and now it all works fine.

Comment: I had deactivated IPvA6 when I was doing some setting up or nordvpn and after I activated it again the problem went away, I thik this might have been the issue. Probably geoclue was trying to access it and having issues.